# Function definition in Lua

Tags: lua

Is there any difference between

```
local splitPathFileExtension = function (res)
end
```

and

```
function splitPathFileExtension(res)
end
```

? I understand in the first case this function is anonymous but this is the only difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are almost exactly the same thing (other than the fact that you've specified the first function as `local` and not the second one.)

See the [manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.5.9) on function definitions:

> The statement
>
> ```
>     function f () body end
> ```
>
> corresponds to
>
> ```
>     f = function () body end
> ```
>
> The statement
>
> ```
>     function t.a.b.c.f () body end
> ```
>
> translates to
>
> ```
>     t.a.b.c.f = function () body end
> ```
>
> The statement
>
> ```
>     local function f () body end
> ```
>
> translates to
>
> ```
>     local f; f = function () body end
> ```
>
> not to
>
> ```
>     local f = function () body end
> ```
>
> (This only makes a difference when the body of the function contains references to f.)

Comment: Should be: "you've specified the first _variable_ as local". Functions are values, so they don't have a scope category.

Answer (score 4):

All functions are anonymous, they don't have names. A function definition is in fact an assignment statement that creates a value of type `function` and assigns it to a variable.

The second code is syntactic sugar that's equivalent to:

```
splitPathFileExtension = function (res) end
```

So, other than the first is local while the second is global, there's no difference between the two ways of function definition.

Comment: Note: You have to take the de-sugaring exactly as stated. A variable is global only when it's not local. For example, taking the two assignment statements from the question together in sequence, the local variable splitPathFileExtension is assigned twice.